# Is it possible to customize DatePickerDialog dialog?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently using this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog
What I would like to do is to be able to mark specific dates with a specific color. Say for example march 3 5 and 7 have a red circle around them. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, do you want to mark one date or more?

Comment: @Gabriel14 More than one. I like the look of the popup that appears with DatePickerDialog. I just want to be able to programmatically "mark" special dates with a circle or perhaps that date has a different color or something to distinguish certain dates from others.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another easier way from customizing `DatePickerDialog`!
You can use this great library [Material DateTime Picker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) to achieve your desired features.

**`[DatePickerDialog] setHighlightedDays(Calendar[] days):`**

You can pass a `Calendar[]` of days to highlight within `setHighlightedDays(Calendar[] days)` method. They will be rendered in bold. You can tweak the color of the highlighted days by overwriting `mdtp_date_picker_text_highlighted`
 ([from official doc](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#additional-options))

Comment: @jank29 Did you try this library?